# How to make the switch to C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been programming in C++ for a while now, but mostly things centered around the low-level features of C++. By that I mean mostly working with pointers and raw arrays. I think this behavior is known as using C++ as C with classes. Despite this, I only having tried C recently for the first time. I was pleasantly surprised how languages like C# and Java hide these details away in convenient standard library classes like Dictionaries and Lists.

I'm aware that the C++ standard library has many containers like vectors, maps and strings as well and C++11 only adds to this by having std:: array and ranged loops.

How do I best learn to make use of these modern language features and which are suitable for which moments? Is it correct that software engineering in C++ nowadays is mostly free of manual memory management?

Lastly, which compiler should I use to make the most of the new standard? Visual Studio has excellent debugging tools, but even VS2012 seems to have terrible C++11 support.

Comment: I'd say calling VS2012's C++11 support "terrible" is a bit exaggerated, but it certainly could be better (missing initializer lists is especially annoying for test/toy code). But note that they announced that they will be shipping compiler updates independently of the rest of VS, so I guess we can hope for quite a few C++11 features in VS2012 in the course of 2013.

Comment: At first I thought suggesting it for learning C++11 would be odd, but seeing that you are still stuck in _C-With-Classes_ land... A decade ago I read Koenig/Moo's _Accelerated C++_. By the time I was actually already doing template meta-programming (I only read it for a review), but it still felt like a revelation. (I used it as a base for teaching C++ ever since.) Coming from _C With Classes_, the book can show you a whole new language you didn't know you had at your disposal. It's only 250 pages, and you can then quickly advance to something C++11-specific, but IMO it's a worthwhile step.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, some rules of thumb:

- Use `std::unique_ptr` as a no-overhead smart pointer. You shouldn’t need to bother with raw pointers all that often. `std::shared_ptr` is likewise unnecessary in most cases. A desire for shared ownership often betrays a lack of thought about ownership in the first place.
- Use `std::array` for static-length arrays and `std::vector` for dynamic.
- Use generic algorithms extensively, in particular:

  - `<algorithm>`
  - `<numeric>`
  - `<iterator>`
  - `<functional>`
- Use `auto` and `decltype()` wherever they benefit readability. In particular, when you want to declare a thing, but of a type that you don’t care about such as an iterator or complex template type, use `auto`. When you want to declare a thing in terms of the type of another thing, use `decltype()`.
- Make things type-safe when you can. When you have assertions that enforce invariants on a particular kind of thing, that logic can be centralised in a type. And this doesn’t necessarily make for any runtime overhead. It should also go without saying that C-style casts (`(T)x`) should be avoided in favour of the more explicit (and searchable!) C++-style casts (e.g., `static_cast`).
- Finally, know how the rule of three:

  - Destructor
  - Copy constructor
  - Assignment operator

  Has become the rule of five with the addition of the move constructor and move assignment operator. And understand rvalue references in general and how to avoid copying.

C++ is a complex language, so it’s difficult to characterise how best to use *all* of it. But the practices of good C++ development haven’t changed fundamentally with C++11. You should still prefer memory-managed containers over manual memory management—smart pointers make it easy to efficiently do this.

I would say that modern C++ is indeed mostly free of manual memory management—the advantage to C++’s memory model is that it’s *deterministic*, not that it’s manual. Predictable deallocations make for more predictable performance.

As for a compiler, G++ and Clang are both competitive in terms of C++11 features, and rapidly catching up on their deficiencies. I don’t use Visual Studio, so I can speak neither for nor against it.

Finally, a note about `std::for_each`: avoid it in general.

`transform`, `accumulate`, and `erase`–`remove_if` are good old functional `map`, `fold`, and `filter`. But `for_each` is more general, and therefore less meaningful—it doesn’t express any *intent* other than looping. Besides that, it’s used in the same situations as range-based `for`, and is syntactically heavier, even when used point-free. Consider:

```
for (const auto i : container)
    std::cout << i << '\n';

std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](int i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
});

for (const auto i : container)
    frobnicate(i);

std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), frobnicate);
```

Comment: Are there some binding principles to these rules of thumb?  It seems like a nice list of suggestions, but...  As an outsider arriving to this question via Google, how does your answer help me pick up C++11 in a principled way, and use it without wrapping myself around the C++ axle?

Comment: +1 for the list, but I have a small nitpick: when (rightly) warning against `std::for_each` I would have expected the range based for loop as a better replacement than plain `for`.

Comment: @FabioFracassi: Oops. I wrote *plain* to contrast with `std::for_each`, not with *range-based*. I’ve removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would update if it wasn't for `std::for_each()`. When you have lambda, it's certainly better than a traditional `for` loop. With a range-based `for` loop that might not be the case, but you didn't write "range-based `for` loop".

Comment: @sbi: In my mind, the term “`for` loop” includes “range-based `for` loop”. I have edited with more explanation and an example to clarify, thank you.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I understand that it _includes_ that. However, I dispute that a traditional `for` loop is better than `std::for_each()`. In fact, I believe it's the opposite. Anyway, this now gets my upvote. `:)`

Comment: `Use std::unique_ptr as a no-overhead smart pointer.` It is NOT a no-overhead smart pointer. Just compare the resulting assembly code for proof. (Or your can logically reason that destructors must be called even in the event of exceptions causing the stack to unwind to realize this.) You should rectify this to be `Use std::unique_ptr as an almost no-overhead smart pointer.`

Comment: @ThomasEding: If it does what I was going to do anyway, except for the bugs I might have written without it, then I think it’s reasonable to call it no-overhead.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I'm just being pedantic for those that want to know how it really is. Suppose no exception can happen in `{Foo * f = new Foo(); delete f;}` as well as in `{std::unique_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo());}` They are semantically identical, yet generate different machine code.

Comment: @ThomasEding: Just saying "it generates different code!" doesn't mean a whole lot.  Difference is not necessarily overhead.

Answer (score 13):

As a starting point:

- Stop using `char*` for strings. Use `std::string` or `std::wstring` and just watch your code get shorter, more readable, and safer
- Stop using C-style arrays (things declared with `[ ]`) and use `std::vector` or some other appropriate container class. The nice things about `std::vector` are that it knows its own length, it cleans up its contents when it goes out of scope, it is easy to iterate over, and it makes itself bigger when you add more items. But there are other collections that might work even better for your circumstances.
- Use `std::unique_ptr` - and learn `std::move` almost immediately. Since this may result in some noncopyable objects, laziness may occasionally send you towards `std::shared_ptr` - and you may have some genuine use cases for `std::shared_ptr` as well
- Use `auto` when declaring iterators and types that depend on earlier declarations (eg earlier you declared a vector of something, now you're declaring a something, use `auto`)
- Use algorithms and `for_each` over a "raw for" whenever you can since it spares others from reading your loop carefully to conclude that you're in fact iterating over the whole collection etc. If your compiler supports "range for" then use it over `for_each`. Learn trivial algorithm calls like `iota`, `generate`, `accumulate`, `find_if` and so on.
- Use lambdas - they are the easy way to leverage algorithms. They also open the door to so much more.

Don't get too worked up about what compiler to use. The "terrible, awful" lack of C++ 11 support in VS2012 is that there isn't variadic templates (yeah right, you were *just about* to use variadic templates) and the `{}` initializer isn't there. I want that too but I'm hardly going to stop using a useful development tool over it.

The second thing to do, after embracing `std::`, is to start thinking RAII. Anytime you have

- starting action
- series of actions with something you got from starting action
- cleanup action that needs to happen even in the case of exceptions

Then what you have is a constructor, a number of member functions, and a destructor. Write a class that takes care of that for you. You might not even have to write the ctor and the dtor. Putting a `shared_ptr` as a member variable of a class is an example of RAII - you don't write memory management code, but when your instance goes out of scope, the right things will happen. Expand that thinking to cover things like closing files, releasing handles, locks etc and code will just get simpler and smaller (while eliminating leaks) before your eyes.

If you're feeling really confident, purge `printf` in favour of `cout`, get rid of macros (`#define`stuff), and start learn some "advanced idioms" like PIMPL. I have a [whole course on this](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/adv-cpp) at Pluralsight which you can probably watch using their free trial.

Comment: I like how you are sarcastic about him not using variadic templates anytime soon, but I think missing uniform initialization is missing something really important for everyday programming.

Comment: Can't wait for initializer lists ... waiting to find out when we'll get them ...

Comment: Another important lack in VS2012 are "rvalue references v3", i.e. the _automatic generated_ move constructor and move assign.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I best learn to make use of these modern language features and which are suitable for which moments?

By programming. Experience is the best way to learn.

C++11 has lots of new features (auto, rvalue, new smart pointers - just to name few). The best start is to just start using them, and read about them whenever you can, and whenever you find an interesting article.

> Is it correct that software engineering in C++ nowadays is mostly free of manual memory management?

That depends what you need to do. Most applications can get away with smart pointers, and forget about memory management. There are still applications that can not get away so easily (for example if they need placement new, or a custom memory allocator for whatever reason).

If you need to use Qt, you'll have to use their rules for memory management.

> which compiler should I use to make the most of the new standard?

Whatever you have at hand that supports the latest standard :

- gcc has [good support for c++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) features
- vs has [list of features](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127043203/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

but no compiler supports all features.

Answer (score -7):

My university is still using C++ for teaching. I have programmed with C++ for 5 years and now I am a graduate student. Of course, now I am using a lot Java, Ruby etc. 
I really recommend you don't too hurry about those features in language like Java. In my experience and opinion, after the low level features of C++. You should look into topics like generic programming with C/C++ like making template class, template functions, operator overritten, virtual methods, smart pointers. 
For the Object Oriented Design Part, there are lots of features C++ have and Java does not, like multi-inheritance. Inheritance is powerful but dangerous too. The implementation level of object oriented design in C++ is a good topic too. 
Inter-process communication, threadings, are important in C++ too.

For the compiler and debugger. I know visual studio is awesome. But I really recommend you learn GDB, Valgrind, and Make still, and be good at these tools. Microsoft is awesome, but it did too many things for you. As a student, you really need to learn those things which Microsoft did too you. For the compiler, G++ is good from GNU.

After all, after so many years, I really feel, the most important things are the low level features like raw array. Vector is really just a dynamic array. 
These are my recommendations, something maybe too subjective, just take what you think is right.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is not about learning C++ in general, but switching to C++11.